# If Else Function in Sharepoint List

Tags: list, sharepoint, formula

I've been trying several formula but is not successful.

How do I proceed only with my computation of adding Column2 and Column3 if the Value in Column1 is NOT Blank

Else display "not valid"

I am new into Sharepoint list but the formula is not similar to Excel.

Proceed only with the mathematical formula when column1 is not blank

Comment: Please add more code and what you have done and where you stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Apply this formula to your calculated column:

```
=IF(column1="","not valid",column2+column3)
```

Test result:
[image]